# OAuth 2.0 request in Picasa API

Tags: .net, oauth, google-api

For graduation article purposes I'm developing a Windows Phone App client of Picasa API without using any library.

I was able to do the first 5 steps listed here: https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/docs/2.0/developers_guide_protocol#Auth

But how do I do the step 6 "attach token to the request"?
 Your application requests user data, attaching the access token to the request.

I tried using HTTP Header Authentication: Bearer [access token] and query string ?access_token=[Token]

Both didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would help if you post your code up here, but yes basically querystring ?access_token= should work. Did you use client side or server side authentication?

Server side authentication actually has one extra step. You need to swap the "code" for the "token".

After that, it's just a matter of sticking the access token in the querystring. I have an active working project that has this WCF contract signature:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IPicasaWeb
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "data/feed/api/user/{userId}?kind=photo&alt=json&access_token={accessToken}&max-results={perPage}&start-index={startIndex}&access={access}",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
        Method="GET")]
    Photos GetPhotos(string userId, string accessToken = null, int startIndex = 1, int perPage = 30, string access = "visible");
}
```